# Using the mac app, Music.app, I can go to the Music Store but how do I search for an artist or a song

Tags: macos, itunes, music

I'm using the Music.app on my iMac running Catalina. When I enter the Apple Music Store how do i search for an artist or a particular album or song?  I hope this is not a stupid question, but I've looked everywhere for a search box. I have found a way but its convoluted and doesn't work all the time.  If anyone knows how to search on the App Music Store using the Music app please let me know?  Thanks.  Do i have to load iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Music app, click in the Search bar at the top of the left sidebar. When you do that buttons will appear on the right to select either Apple Music or Your Library. You can search for artists, albums or songs. Note that I subscribe to Apple Music, so your details may vary if you don't, but I think the search should work just as well.

[image: Screen shot]

I tried signing out and got similar results - plus an iTunes Store button! So give it a try.

[image]

Comment: oh geez! how did i miss that? lol...  Thank you for that!